# Can there exist any continuous function on R that maps a rational number to an irrational number and an irrational number to a rational number?

Tags: real-analysis

Can there exist any continuous function on $R$ that maps a rational number to an irrational number and an irrational number to a rational number?

Comment: Sure.  Indeed, "most" continuous functions do this.  The function $x \mapsto x - \mathrm{e}$ gets the job done, for example ($0 \mapsto -\mathrm{e}$ is a rational going to an irrational, and $\mathrm{e} \mapsto  0$ is an irrational going to a rational).

Answer (score 5):

As stated, the answer is yes. For instance, $f(x)=x\sqrt2$ maps $1$ to $\sqrt2$ and maps $\sqrt2$ to  $2$.

If your question is whether there is some continuous real function $f$ such that $f(\mathbb Q) = \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and $f(\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q) = \mathbb Q$, then the answer is no, even if we forego continuity.
This is because of a cardinality argument: $\mathbb Q$ is countable, and so $f(\mathbb Q)$ must be countable too.
However, $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The image would be countable, but the continuous image of a connected set is connected.  A connected subset of $\mathbf R$ with more than one point contains an interval, and is uncountable.

I am taking the question to ask for a function that maps every rational to an irrational, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take $$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$ then $\sqrt{2} \mapsto 1$ and $2 \mapsto \sqrt{2}.$

There is no such function to take *every* rational to an irrational and *every* irrational to a rational.